# Programmatically executing a node search

Tags: 8, search

Is it possible to programmatically execute a node search? Maybe via [NodeSearch](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21Search%21NodeSearch.php/class/NodeSearch/8.8.x) or [Drupal\search](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/namespace/Drupal%21search/8.8.x)?

The closest I could get was to programmatically do stuff such as:

```php
\Drupal::service('search.index')->clear();

echo \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.search')->getCacheMaxAge();
```

Note that I don't want to use `search_api` but simply what Drupal 8 provides out of the box as a response to `/search/node?keys=test`. Also note that I don't wish to integrate via HTTP.

Comment: What do you want to use the results for?

Comment: @Jdrupal get the `nid`s which match and return them on a custom JSON api response.

Comment: Can't you just make an entity query?

Comment: @Jdrupal yes of course, but that would need a lot of code. I would also like to have the exact search result characteristics of Drupal search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that with the search plugin used by the search page entity with the **node_search** id.

```
use Drupal\search\Entity\SearchPage;

// Default is the node_search page.
$id = \Drupal::service('search.search_page_repository')->getDefaultSearchPage();
$defaultSearchPage = SearchPage::load($id);
$searchPlugin = $defaultSearchPage->getPlugin();
$searchPlugin->setSearch($keywords, $parameters, $arguments);
$searchPlugin->buildResults(); // $searchPlugin->execute() works too if you want raw results
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. It took me time to figure out what data to use for $parameters and $arguments. Eventually got it working by using request class. i.e $searchPlugin->setSearch($keywords, \Drupal::request()->query->all(), \Drupal::request()->attributes->all());